# Get cpuid for a particular process thread using ps

Tags: cpu, process, ps, threads

How do I get the ps command to output just the cpuid if I know the pid and tid?

I can use `ps -e -mo pid,tid,psr | grep Thread_Id` to display the current cpu the thread is running on, but is there a way to get just 'psr' without having to process the resulting output string:

```
$ ps -e -mo pid,tid,psr | grep 4360
$  -   4360   0 <-- thread 4360 on cpu0
```

Instead just print

```
$ 0
```

Something like `ps -p Process_Id -t Thread_Id -o psr` <-- This obviously doesn't work.

Or any alternate command other than "ps" that will get the job done?

Comment: So you're just trying to further narrow the results down to the third column only, correct?

Comment: @n8te: Yes, want a command to directly output only the cpuid, if I have the process and thread IDs.

Comment: You could pass the results to an awk command. Try this out and tell me if it gives the results you are looking for: `ps -e -mo pid,tid,psr | grep 4360 | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: This should have worked but isn't... it prints '-' followed by the cpuid on the next line. I'm looking to output just the cpuid. Does it work for you?

Comment: Use this instead:  `ps -e -mo pid,tid,psr | grep 4360 | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'`

Comment: Yes, that works fine